# Mutation problem with object filtering in Javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, immutability

I started with react a few months ago and I thought I understood mutations well enough until now.

I have a function that accepts an object, selected itemId, and parentId (optional). Data can have nested elements upto 1 level. What i need to do is change the value of the key `selected` if the itemId matches. If the itemId is inside a parent, then I need to set `selected` inside that object.

Another use case is, if the itemId is the id of the parent. In this case I need to set the value of selected of all the children as well. And this where the problem comes. 
When I am trying to set the children's `selected` value, the function is mutating the data that I am sending, and therefore returning wrong results.

Here is the function in question:

```
function returnSelectedItems(data, itemId, parentId) {
  // created this object trying to rule out mutation problem in the tests. @see tests file.
  const originalData = data.map(item => item);
  if (parentId) {
    // if parent id is present, a child element has been selected, then directly go to the element
    // go through all the items
    return originalData.map(parentItem => {
      // see if the id matches the parent item
      if (parentItem.id === parentId) {
        // if yes, check if it contains any children
        if (parentItem.children && parentItem.children.length > 0) {
          // iterate through their children and assign the resulting array as the children for the parent
          parentItem.children = parentItem.children.map(childItem => {
            // find the child with the id selected and change its value
            if (childItem.id === itemId) {
              childItem.selected = !childItem.selected;
            }
            return childItem;
          });
        }
      }
      return parentItem;
    });
  } else {
    return originalData.map(item => {
      if (item.id === itemId) {
        // set the item to the opposite it was before
        item.selected = !item.selected;

        // if it has children, we have to set the values for all of them.
        if (item.children && item.children.length > 0) {
          item.children = item.children.map(childItem => {
            childItem.selected = item.selected;
            return childItem;
          });
        }
      }
      return item;
    });
  }
}
```

And here are the tests that I created to test if this works as expected:

```
test('WITHOUT children test for selectedItems function', () => {
  const data = [
    {
      id: 1,
      name: 'test',
      selected: false
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      name: 'test',
      selected: false
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      name: 'test',
      selected: false
    },
    {
      id: 4,
      name: 'test',
      selected: false
    },
    {
      id: 5,
      name: 'test',
      selected: false
    }
  ];
  expect(returnSelectedItems(data, 4)).toEqual(
    data.map(item => {
      if (item.id === 4) {
        item.selected = true;
      }
      return item;
    })
  );
  expect(returnSelectedItems(data, 5)).toEqual(
    data.map(item => {
      if (item.id === 5) {
        item.selected = true;
      }
      return item;
    })
  );
  expect(
    returnSelectedItems(
      data.map(item => {
        if (item.id === 4) {
          item.selected = true;
        }
        return item;
      }, 4)
    )
  ).toEqual(data);
  expect(
    returnSelectedItems(
      data.map(item => {
        if (item.id === 5) {
          item.selected = true;
        }
        return item;
      }, 5)
    )
  ).toEqual(data);
});

test('WITH children test for selectedItems function', () => {
  const data = [
    {
      id: 1,
      name: 'test',
      selected: false,
      children: [{id: 1, name: 'test', selected: false}, {id: 2, name: 'test', selected: false}, {id: 3, name: 'test', selected: false}]
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      name: 'test',
      selected: false,
      children: [{id: 1, name: 'test', selected: false}, {id: 2, name: 'test', selected: false}, {id: 3, name: 'test', selected: false}]
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      name: 'test',
      selected: false,
      children: [{id: 1, name: 'test', selected: false}, {id: 2, name: 'test', selected: false}, {id: 3, name: 'test', selected: false}]
    },
    {
      id: 4,
      name: 'test',
      selected: false,
      children: [{id: 1, name: 'test', selected: false}, {id: 2, name: 'test', selected: false}, {id: 3, name: 'test', selected: false}]
    },
    {
      id: 5,
      name: 'test',
      selected: false,
      children: [{id: 1, name: 'test', selected: false}, {id: 2, name: 'test', selected: false}, {id: 3, name: 'test', selected: false}]
    }
  ];

  const backupData = [
    {
      id: 1,
      name: 'test',
      selected: false,
      children: [{id: 1, name: 'test', selected: false}, {id: 2, name: 'test', selected: false}, {id: 3, name: 'test', selected: false}]
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      name: 'test',
      selected: false,
      children: [{id: 1, name: 'test', selected: false}, {id: 2, name: 'test', selected: false}, {id: 3, name: 'test', selected: false}]
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      name: 'test',
      selected: false,
      children: [{id: 1, name: 'test', selected: false}, {id: 2, name: 'test', selected: false}, {id: 3, name: 'test', selected: false}]
    },
    {
      id: 4,
      name: 'test',
      selected: false,
      children: [{id: 1, name: 'test', selected: false}, {id: 2, name: 'test', selected: false}, {id: 3, name: 'test', selected: false}]
    },
    {
      id: 5,
      name: 'test',
      selected: false,
      children: [{id: 1, name: 'test', selected: false}, {id: 2, name: 'test', selected: false}, {id: 3, name: 'test', selected: false}]
    }
  ];

  // this console log is correct
  console.log(data.filter(item => item.id === 4)[0]);
  const dataBack = returnSelectedItems(data, 4);
  // this console is also correct
  console.log(dataBack.filter(item => item.id === 4)[0]);
  // but here the value of the data is changed
  console.log(data.filter(item => item.id === 4)[0]);

  // this passes, but it shouldn't
  expect(returnSelectedItems(data, 4)).toEqual(
    data.map(item => {
      if (item.id === 4) {
        item.selected = true;
      }
      return item;
    })
  );

  // this should pass but it does not
  expect(backupData).toEqual(data);
});
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `const originalData = data.map(item => item)` only creates a shallow copy of the `data` array. And hence whatever `object` item you modify in the `originalData` array will result in mutation of the `data` array. And hence you must deep copy the `data` array. Use a library like [Lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#cloneDeep) for convenience.

Comment: Perfect! thanks! This solves the problem.
BTW, for others having similar problems, I only imported `lodash.clonedeep` in my app using `yarn add lodash.clonedeep`. Then `import cloneDeep from 'lodash.clonedeep'; const originalData = cloneDeep(data);`